# Xamarin Forms - Master Detail page with empty space

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having a problem with my project.

On "App.xaml.cs" i check user preferences, if there's a value the user go to page 1, if no value found the user go to page 2.

Page 2 load ok, without any problem.

But page 1(where I'm using Master Detail page) have a problem on interface. I don't know how it happened, i just reopened my project a minutes ago, tried to compile and then i got this. Can someone help me, please?

[a white empty space between the notification bar and the title bar of the master detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJTam.jpg)

App.Xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
InitializeComponent();
bool hasKey = Preferences.ContainsKey("sess");
if (hasKey == true)
{
var mySession = Preferences.Get("sess", "");
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Master());
}
else
{
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Forms.LoginWithSocialIconPage());
}
}
```

MasterMaster.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
<ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
<ListView.Header>
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="30"/>
<RowDefinition Height="80"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="10"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="circleFrame" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" CornerRadius="10" IsClippedToBounds="True">
<Image x:Name="circleImg" Source="icon.png"></Image>
</Frame>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="White" Text="Nome" FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}" Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>
</Grid>
</ListView.Header>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
<StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="18"/>
</StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

MasterDetail.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Thinkzr.MasterDetail" Title="Título">
<StackLayout Padding="10">
<Label Text="Conteúdo carregado aqui"/>
<!--<Image Source="icon.png"/>-->
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Master.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Thinkzr.Master" xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Thinkzr">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
<pages:MasterMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
<NavigationPage>
<x:Arguments>
<pages:MasterDetail />
</x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the relevant code

Comment: sorry. i just added the code

Comment: you should not wrap MasterDetail inside of a NavigationPage

Comment: the MasterDetail pages were generated by Visual Studio, i just added de frame+image on the menu, i didnt changed the code. It was working early morning, but now i have this problem...

Comment: I mean this `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Master());`

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you help me? What should i do?

Comment: remove the NavigationPage

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If it's possible, can you tell me why i can't wrap MasterDetail inside of NavigationPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#creating-a-masterdetailpage)

> A MasterDetailPage is designed to be a root page, and using it as a
> child page in other page types could result in unexpected and
> inconsistent behavior.